# statvfs wrong SD available size returned

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to monitor the available SD card size in a embedded linux system (petalinux).

After looking for this topic around stackoverflow I learn that a good option is to use the statvfs  structure.

So to test it I wrote the next code:

```
int main()
{
  struct statvfs stat;

  if (statvfs("/run/media/mmcblk1p2", &stat) != 0) {
    // error happens, just quits here
    return -1;
  }
  printf("bsize: %ld\n", stat.f_bsize);
  printf("bavail: %ld\n", stat.f_blocks);
  printf("size in bytes: %ld\n", stat.f_blocks*stat.f_bavail);
  double megas= (((double)(stat.f_blocks*stat.f_bavail)) / (1024*1024));
  printf("size in MB:%.0f \n", megas);

  return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
bsize: 131072
bavail: 973877
size in bytes: 945460243017
size in MB:901661
```

Checking this with the df command I've got:

```
root@petalinux:~# df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                484744         4    484740   0% /dev
tmpfs                  1023712       128   1023584   0% /run
tmpfs                  1023712        88   1023624   0% /var/volatile
/dev/mmcblk1p2       124656256    391168 124265088   0% /run/media/mmcblk1p2
/dev/mmcblk1p1          204607    135889     68719  66% /run/media/mmcblk1p1

root@petalinux:~# df -h
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                473.4M      4.0K    473.4M   0% /dev
tmpfs                   999.7M    128.0K    999.6M   0% /run
tmpfs                   999.7M     88.0K    999.6M   0% /var/volatile
/dev/mmcblk1p2          118.9G    382.0M    118.5G   0% /run/media/mmcblk1p2
/dev/mmcblk1p1          199.8M    132.7M     67.1M  66% /run/media/mmcblk1p1
```

I would expect for the mmcblk1p2 folder an available space of 124265088 bytes but instead I'm having 945460243017 bytes.

I've already had a look to similar questions but unfortunately non of them helped me to solve this issue.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

As pointed it could be the a block multiplication issue,  where I had:

```
stat.f_blocks*stat.f_bavail
```

And I changed it to:

```
 stat.f_frsize*stat.f_bavail
```

But the result still wrong:

```
bsize: 131072
bavail: 973877
size in bytes: 127247450112
Size in MB:121353
```

Now it's showing 127247450112 and it should be 124265088, Any ideas what I've got wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 124265088 kilobytes?

Comment: @user253751, thank you very much, silly mistake, I thought that the df values where in bytes, so I'm having correct results.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
printf("size in bytes: %ld\n", stat.f_blocks*stat.f_bavail);
```

is multiplying two block counts, which surely is not what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely get a wrong answer when multiplying an unsigned long type (f_bsize and f_frsize) by an unsigned long long (f_blocks, f_bfree and f_bavail) without first casting the unsigned long as an unsigned long long...  Try this:

printf("%llu\n", stat.f_bavail * (unsigned long long)stat.f_frsize);